# seleccionar el valor de varias columnas en la vista de Laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-blade, blade

La tabla flores, tiene varias columnas, las cuales son:
**id, monto, nombre1, nombre2 y nombre3**

Este es el código del controlador para llamar los resultados con un id mayor a 5:

```
$flores = Flores::where('id','>','5')->get(); 
return view('inicio', compact('flores') );
```

Me gustaría poder imprimir las columnas de esta forma. sin necesidad de llamar a cada una de ellas directamente.

Esto es lo que tengo en la vista de inicio:

```
@foreach ($flores as $item) 
    $i = 1;
  <h1> {{$item->nombre.$i}} </h1>
    $i++;
@endforeach
```

Lo podría poner de la forma siguiente y me correría sin problemas.

```
@foreach ($flores as $item) 

<h1> {{$item->nombre1}} </h1>
<h1> {{$item->nombre2}} </h1>
<h1> {{$item->nombre3}} </h1>

@endforeach
```

Pero me parece algo tedioso.

Me podrían decir una solución para llamarlas sin necesidad de ponerlo de esa forma?

Comment: No se entiende tu duda, si la puedes explicar mejor nos ayudaría a ayudarte

Comment: Si puedes agregar un ejemplo de como es que esperas la salida sería incluso mejor

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias

Comment: Es que en caso de que sean mas columnas como planeo hacer seria muy incomodo el declarar cada columna para que se muestre, con un for que lo haga por mi, seria mucho mas sencillo

Comment: Creo que tendrías que anidar un `@for` con una variable que vaya entre 1 y 3 para las columnas, pues el `@foreach` es para las filas.

Comment: Puedes mostrarlo en codigo? asi te entiendo mas facil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te decía de anidar un `@for`:

```
@foreach ($flores as $item) // este @foreach para las filas
    @for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) // este @for para los atributos
        <h1> {{ $item->{'nombre'.$i} }} </h1>
    @endfor
@endforeach
```

Otra que se me ocurre. Declarar una variable con los atributos y anidar un `@foreach` sobre esa variable:

```
@php($atributos = ['nombre1', 'nombre2', 'nombre3'])
@foreach ($flores as $item)
    @foreach ($atributos as $atributo)
        <h1> {{ $item->$atributo }} </h1>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Otra más, si quieres iterar sobre todos los atributos del modelo:

```
@foreach ($flores as $item)
    @foreach($item->getAttributes() as $key => $value)
        <h1> {{ $value }} </h1>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, en serio lo necesitaba. No sabia que entre corchetes tambien se podia poner el nombre de la columna.

Comment: Lo de los corchetes es para poder concatenar ahí mismo el string `'nombre'` con el valor de la varible `$i`. Puedes leer más [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php) bajo el título **Sintaxis compleja (llaves)**.